# How does Remove works in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relationship name `:RELTYPE` with a property array called `LineIds`.

Assume,

```
(node1)-[r:RELTYPE {LineIds : [1,2,15]}]->(node2)
```

I want to remove a very specific value from the `r.LineIds` array (let's say 15).

The code written doesn't seem to work. I am trying to remove "15" from the `r.LineIds` array.

```
var lineId = 15
var match = "(t:Template)-[r1:DEPENDS_ON]->(e:Template)"
this.client.Cypher.Match(match)
   .Where((Template t) => t.Id == this.source.Id && t.ScenarioId == sid1)
   .AndWhere((Segment e) => e.Id == this.dest.Id)
   .Remove(lineId+" In r.LineIds")
   .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

In Neo4j Browser

```
match (b :Template)-[r:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG1]->(dim2 :Natural_Account)
where b.Id = 228 and b.ScenarioId = 200 and dim2.Id =117
remove 15 in r.LineIds
delete 15
```

I have also tried [15] instead of just 15 in the remove. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone please help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Not surprising you're having trouble, there isn't a way in Cypher to selectively remove an item from a list. But you can replace the list with one that has the value filtered out.

With just Cypher, you can do this:

```
match (b :Template)-[r:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG1]->(dim2 :Natural_Account)
where b.Id = 228 and b.ScenarioId = 200 and dim2.Id =117
set r.LineIds = filter(val in r.LineIds where val <> 15)
```

If you have access to APOC Procedures, there's one that is a bit easier to use:

```
match (b :Template)-[r:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG1]->(dim2 :Natural_Account)
where b.Id = 228 and b.ScenarioId = 200 and dim2.Id =117
set r.LineIds = apoc.coll.removeAll(r.LineIds, [15])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out the filter method though. I'll try the apoc call, it looks way too easier. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the developer manual of neo4j where for [list operations](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/list/) remove is not a function used for list but used to [remove](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/clauses/remove/) a property/label of a node.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

Filtering out the values that I wish to remove was one of the solution that worked for me.

The Query written below worked fine.

```
match (b :Template)-[r:Temp_Reffered_DIM_SEG1]->(dim2 :Natural_Account)
where b.Id = 228 and b.ScenarioId = 200 and dim2.Id =117
Set r.LineIds = filter(x in r.LineIds where not(x=15))
```

Code for calling Neo4j DB from .net class

```
var lineId = 15
var match = "(t:Template)-[r1:DEPENDS_ON]->(e:Template)"
this.client.Cypher.Match(match)
   .Where((Template t) => t.Id == this.source.Id && t.ScenarioId == sid1)
   .AndWhere((Segment e) => e.Id == this.dest.Id)
   .Set(string.Format("r.LineIds = filter(x in r.LineIds where not(x={0}))",lineId))
   .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Thats it.

Thanks for your answers.